# Как написать аналог командной строки на c++?

Tags: c++, командная-строка

Мне задали написать самый простой аналог командной строки c++. Если честно, я в душе не е..знаю как ее делать) Может есть хоть какие-нибудь статьи или гайды? Потому что я вообще ничего не нашел.

Comment: Гуглите на тему "shell на С++"

Comment: Я бы ещё погуглил custom shell c++ github так ещё и код будет - вот первая ссылка (но я ее не открыл) https://github.com/rahulbahal7/custom-shell

Answer (score 3):

Командная строка в грубом рассмотрении представляет из себя достаточно простую функциональность. Она считывает команду, выполняет действия и показывает при необходимости вывод.

Поэтому самый простой аналог наверное будет такой:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
 
int main()
{   
    while(true)
    {
        std::string command;
        std::cout << "$>";
        std::cin >> command;
        
        if(command == "hi")
            std::cout << "Oh, hi!" << std::endl;
        if(command == "exit")
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

А дальше только стоит наращивать фукнциональность в зависимости от введенных команд и требований: установить текущую папку перед работой, переход по директориям, вывод файлов в директории и работа с ними, запуск других *.exe т.д. Все остальное зависит только от того, насколько сложной должна быть ваша собственная командная строка и какие возможности поддерживать.

Comment: Окей. Но я бы добавил ещё пару строк про fork & execv парсинг PATH и LD_LIBRARY_PATH да еще и pipe хотелось бы иметь)

Comment: @Maggot есть у меня небольшое подозрение, что писаться это дело будет под Windows на аналог CMD строки. Ну еще такую статейку нашел, чтобы самому не расписывать: https://tproger.ru/translations/unix-shell-in-c/ Хотя про path и pipe там конечно ни слова.